# queried inside controller so how can i access id in that through apex test class?

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

[image]

How can I test below code which is inside controller?

```
public with sharing class AccountDetails{
    public Id accRecId;
    public  List<account> accRec { get; set; }  

  public ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public AccountDetails(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.controller=controller;
        accRecId =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        if(accRecId != null){            
            accRec =  [select id,name,Rating,AccountNumber,Phone,Type,Industry,(select id,FirstName,LastName,Phone from contacts),
                       (select id, name,CloseDate,StageName from Opportunities ) from account where id=:accRecId];            
        }
    }  
}
```

---

```
@isTest
public class TestAccDetails {
    @isTest
  public static void testSesion()
    {       
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name='Test Account' ;
        insert a;      
         Test.StartTest();
        ApexPages.StandardController ctrl = new ApexPages.StandardController(a);
        AccountDetails ext = new AccountDetails(ctrl);
        PageReference myVfPage = Page.AccountDetailRelatedPage;
        myVfPage.getParameters().put('accId', String.valueOf(a.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',a.Id);
          Test.StopTest();



       // List<Account> accRecList = [select id,name,Rating,AccountNumber,Phone,Type,Industry,(select id,FirstName,LastName,Phone from contacts),
       //                             (select id, name,CloseDate,StageName from Opportunities ) from account where id=:a.Id];        
       // System.assertEquals('Test Account', accRecList[0].Name); 
        //System.assertEquals('Hot', accRecList[0].Rating); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Its better to copy and paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test class need some tweaks.

1) You should use parameter `Id` instead of `accId`

2) `Test.setCurrentPage` should be set before calling controller methods.

Try with below test class and check

```
@isTest
public class TestAccDetails {
    @isTest
    public static void testSesion()
    {       
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name='Test Account' ;
        insert a;      

        Test.StartTest();

        PageReference myVfPage = Page.AccountDetailRelatedPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',a.Id);

        ApexPages.StandardController ctrl = new ApexPages.StandardController(a);
        AccountDetails ext = new AccountDetails(ctrl);

        Test.StopTest();

        //...Assertions here...
    }
}
```

Also I recommend to update your controller code to

```
accRecId = controller.getId();
```

Instead of fetching from url parameter.